# Mock a library method response using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am new to pytest, i want to create a test for a method called inside a library. So following is my sample usecase.

I have a python library called **core**:

- Inside **core** there is a folder called **p_core**.
- Inside **p_core** there is python file **common.py**
- In this **common.py** file, there is a class **CommonBase**, this class have following method

```
def get_timestamp(input_example):
  # I have an import statement in this file that is, import time
  timestamp = time.time()

  return f'{input_example}-{timestamp}'
```

So I want to mock the time.time(), because every time I don't want to get a different timestamp.

following is my pytest code

```
import time
from core.p_core.common import CommonBase


def test_get_timestamp(mocker):
    mock_now = mocker.patch("core.p_core.common.CommonBase.time.time",
                            return_value=1680087494.2400253)

    assert CommonBase.get_timestamp('TEST') == "TEST1680087494.2400253"
```

But I am getting an error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named core.p_core.common.CommonBase**

Please ignore my get_timestamp methods logic, this is just an example.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing looks so strange from your example. Check your path, you should be running `pytest` from the root folder where you have `core` module 

Also, you dont need to set return value again. below line can be removed.
```python
mock_now.return_value = time.time()
```

Comment: @Jerry Thank you. Yeah, even I don't know why I am getting that **ModuleNotFoundError**. Also, I have removed that return statement. While importing that module I am not getting any errors.

Comment: you need to patch the import in `APISearchBase`, whichever file that is defined in

Comment: @gold_cy thank you. Can you please give an example? Because I am new to pytest, and I didn't get what you mean actually, sorry.

Comment: what is the import path of APISearchBase?

Comment: @gold_cy Sorry that was a mistake, actually it is not APISearchBase, it is CommonBase. I have updated the question.

Comment: In the import statement, I am not getting any errors. But while adding it to the patch I am getting error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.p_core.common.CommonBase'; 'core.p_core' is not a package**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by updating the test_get_timestamp method as follows.

```
def test_get_timestamp(mocker):
    mock_now = mocker.patch("core.p_core.common.time.time",
                            return_value=1680087494.2400253)

    assert CommonBase.get_timestamp('TEST') == "TEST1680087494.2400253"
```

**mock_now = mocker.patch("core.p_core.common.time.time",
return_value=1680087494.2400253)** This was the change. Before I was patching *core.p_core.common.CommonBase.time.time*.
But if we need to mock a method(in my example time.time()) that is imported in common.py(common.py is the file in the above example), then I have to pass this *core.p_core.common.time.time* for mocker.patch